# Dagger Hilt provide alternative Modules for different flavors/build types

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I try to migrate an App to [Dagger Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/). In my old setup I switched a Module for a Debug Version in Debug builds or for different product flavors. E.g.:

```
@Module
open class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    open fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        ...
    }
}

class DebugNetworkModule : NetworkModule() {

    override fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I swapped in the correct Module in Debug builds:

```
val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().networkModule(DebugNetworkModule())
```

Since Hilt manages the `ApplicationComponent` I see no possibility to swap in Modules.

However when I have a look into the generated source code (for me: `DaggerApp_HiltComponents_ApplicationC`) I see that Hilt does generate a Builder for the different Modules (which are unused beside the `ApplicationContextModule`).

I **know** this is not the best practice. It would be cleaner to just provide different `NetworkModule`s for each build type/product flavor. But that would result in lots of duplicated code.

In Tests I can uninstall Modules and install Test Modules. But that seem to be impossible in production code.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The key thing with Hilt is that by default the modules in your source code = the modules installed in your app.

#### Option 1: Separate Code paths

Ideally, you would have alternative modules for the different builds, and separate which ones are used via [sourceSets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#change-default-source-set-configurations)

In release source set:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class) 
@Module
object ReleaseModule {
  @Provides
  fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient { /* Provide some OkHttpClient */ }
}
```

In debug source set:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class) 
@Module
object DebugModule {
  @Provides
  fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient { /* Provide a different OkHttpClient */ }
}
```

#### Option 2: Override using `@BindsOptionalOf`

If option 1 isn't feasible because you want to override a module that's still present in the source, you could use dagger [optional binding](https://dagger.dev/api/2.11/dagger/BindsOptionalOf.html)

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object Module {
  @Provides
  fun provideHttpClient(
    @DebugHttpClient debugOverride: Optional<OkHttpClient>
  ): OkHttpClient {
    return if (debugOverride.isPresent()) {
      debugOverride.get()
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}

@Qualifier annotation class DebugHttpClient

@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class) 
@Module
abstract class DebugHttpClientModule {
  @BindsOptionalOf 
  @DebugHttpClient
  abstract fun bindOptionalDebugClient(): OkHttpClient
}
```

and then in a file only in the debug configuration:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class) 
@Module
object DebugHttpClientModule {
  @Provides 
  @DebugHttpClient
  fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient { ... }
}
```

#### Option 3: Multibinding `@IntoMap`

If you need more granularity that just implmenentation + test/debug override, you could use multibinding and maps, using the key as the priority for which implementation to choose.

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object Module {
  @Provides
  fun provideHttpClient(
    availableClients: Map<Int, @JvmSuppressWildcards OkHttpClient>
  ): OkHttpClient {
    // Choose the available client from the options provided.
    val bestEntry = availableClients.maxBy { it.key }
    return checkNotNull(bestEntry?.value) { "No OkHttpClients were provided" }
  }
}
```

Main application module:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class) 
@Module
object MainModule {
  @Provides 
  @IntoMap 
  @IntKey(0)
  fun provideDefaultHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    ...
  }
}
```

Debug override:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class) 
@Module
object DebugModule {
  @Provides 
  @IntoMap 
  @IntKey(1)
  fun provideDebugHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you use option 3, I would either make the provided type nullable/optional, or refrain from using `@Multibinds` so that things fail at compile time rather than runtime if nothing is bound into the map

Comment: In actual production code, there is code to call and obtain a production object from debug and test.
For example, you can initialize OkHttpClient in the same way as in production and add LoggingInterceptor in debug Dagger module.
In that case I am wondering how to use Dagger Hilt.

`override fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
   super.provideHttpClient().addNetworkInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor()).build()
}`


Currently, I am considering preparing a Factory by myself and overwriting it with a source set such as debug.

Comment: Would dagger multibinding work for your case? https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html

You could bind a set of NetworkInterceptors. You can either have a provider `@IntoSet` that is only present in the debug/test code or have a provider of `@ElementsIntoSet` that returns an empty set in prod and a set with items depending on BuildConfig.DEBUG or some other runtime check

Comment: Thanks for reacting to the suggestions. This pattern seems to work with `@IntoSet` and `@ElementsIntoSet`!
But I need to call the production code in a few other patterns. For example, return a Fake object if that option is enabled in the Debug menu. `override fun provideApi() {if (fakeDebugEnabled) {FakeApi()} else {super.provideApi() }}`. There are other patterns that you can wrap instead of returning Fake to print debug information or change behavior. In that case it is difficult.

Comment: If a module is going to be used in both the debug and non-debug modes, it has to allow for the possibility of the different debug options one way or another, either by taking an interface with multiple implementation, `Sets` of implementations bound with `@IntoSet/@ElementsIntoSet`, or an `Optional` test implementation using `@BindsOptionalOf`

You can also use qualifiers to have multiple bindings for the same interface/class, which might be helpful for your case